# "No converter found for return value of type error" in Spring Boot 2.0.6

Tags: java, spring-boot

I encountered a problem that I thought would be seen by numerous people. I Google'd it for several hours, had no any clue so far.

The problem is, when I follow the "101" lesson for Spring Boot, nothing else, my work is create a model class and use @RestController to return JSON format POJO, I completed that (both on IntelliJ and MyEclipse), when I use 2.0.5.RELEASE, everything just fine, I can get this JSON output:

[image]

When I changed "spring-boot-starter-parent" to 2.0.6.RELEASE, it can't output the right JSON object anymore:

[image]

**In the console of IDE, it shows:**

> 2018-10-28 09:15:33.496  WARN 16784 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class com.wulala.totalconfused.model.Greeting

What the ...

Lesson 101 should be easy, right?

Comment: Can you please show your model and Controller and make sure your model Greeting have getter/setters..

Comment: Are you using Maven? If so, check that it hasn’t corrupted a Jackson jar when it downloaded it.

Comment: I just followed by this link: [link]https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/, same controller and same model.